# Count 2 same attributes from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have received Column ambiguously defined. After entering this SQL statement. 
What I was trying to do is to calculate the number of people attended each event between BusinessEventInvite and EventInvite.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EVENTID, Count(EI.Attended)+Count(BEI.Attended) as TotalAttended
FROM EVENT E
left outer join BUSINESSEVENTINVITE BEI ON E.EVENTID= BEI.eventid
left outer join EVENTINVITE EI on EI.EVENTID = E.EVENTID
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = Attended and BEI.ATTENDED = Attended
GROUP BY E.EVENTID
ORDER BY E.EVENTID ASC;
```

BEI Table

ALUMNIID EVENTID RSVP ATTENDED

```
 1          6 YES        Attended  
 2          6 YES        Attended  
 3          6 YES        Attended  
 4          6 YES        Attended  
 5          6 YES        Attended  
 6          6 NO
```

6 rows selected

EI Table
ALUMNIID EVENTID RSVP ATTENDED

```
 7          6 YES        Attended  
 8          6 YES        Attended  
 9          6 No                   
10          7 YES        Attended  
11          8 YES        Attended  
12          7 YES        Attended  
13          7 YES        Attended  
14          8 YES        Attended  
15          7 YES        Attended  
16          8 YES        Attended
```

10 rows selected

Event Table

EVENTID EVENTNAME

---

```
     6 Annual Social Night           
     7 Annual Social Night           
     8 Annual Social Night           
     9 Annual Social Night
```

Comment: I assume that you have the same person who be in BUSINESSEVENTINVITE  and EVENTINVITE  and in your query you count it twice. Are you want count this people once or twice?

Comment: everyone holds an unique id so it's impossible to have 2 of the same record.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the schema of the tables to be certain if these columns exist in those tables. But generally speaking you get that error when SQL Server finds the same column name in 2 or more tables that you are using in your queries so it is asking you to resolve that ambiguity by qualifying them with the aliases.

My guess is you need to change this line

```
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = Attended and BEI.ATTENDED = Attended
```

to

```
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = BEI.Attended
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably cause of your `WHERE` statement as below

```
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = Attended and BEI.ATTENDED = Attended
```

Which probably should be

```
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = 'Attended' AND BEI.ATTENDED = 'Attended';
```

Consider changing your query and move the condition from `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` like

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EVENTID, Count(EI.Attended)+Count(BEI.Attended) as TotalAttended
FROM EVENT E
left outer join BUSINESSEVENTINVITE BEI ON E.EVENTID= BEI.eventid 
AND BEI.ATTENDED = 'Attended'
left outer join EVENTINVITE EI on EI.EVENTID = E.EVENTID 
AND EI.ATTENDED = 'Attended' 
GROUP BY E.EVENTID
ORDER BY E.EVENTID ASC;
```

Comment: EI.Attended and BEI.Attended is a column with different variable.

Comment: @WeiJun, see edit in answer if it helps. You should clarify this in first place.

Answer (score 0):

ALUMNIID    EVENTID RSVP       ATTENDED

---

```
     1          6 YES        Attended  
     2          6 YES        Attended  
     3          6 YES        Attended  
     4          6 YES        Attended  
     5          6 YES        Attended  
     6          6 NO
```

6 rows selected

ALUMNIID    EVENTID RSVP       ATTENDED

---

```
     7          6 YES        Attended  
     8          6 YES        Attended  
     9          6 No                   
    10          7 YES        Attended  
    11          8 YES        Attended  
    12          7 YES        Attended  
    13          7 YES        Attended  
    14          8 YES        Attended  
    15          7 YES        Attended  
    16          8 YES        Attended
```

10 rows selected

The first table is BEI and second table is EI

Comment: If I got it right, what you need to get the expected result is to rewrite your WHERE clause as follow: WHERE EI.ATTENDED = 'Attended' and BEI.ATTENDED = 'Attended'

Comment: You should edit your question and add aditional information in it not in anwer. It is confuse people who first read you question.

Comment: I tried (WHERE EI.ATTENDED = 'Attended' and BEI.ATTENDED = 'Attended') but they seems to give me different result as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because you have not given attended which table from? because there are 3 table right now.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EVENTID, Count(EI.Attended)+Count(BEI.Attended) as TotalAttended
FROM EVENT E
left outer join BUSINESSEVENTINVITE BEI ON E.EVENTID= BEI.eventid
left outer join EVENTINVITE EI on EI.EVENTID = E.EVENTID
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = BEI.Attended and BEI.ATTENDED = EI.Attended
GROUP BY E.EVENTID
ORDER BY E.EVENTID ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguous column error is due to your Alias not being identified for the where statement since attribute **Attended** exists in multiple tables in this query. You probably mean to use the string 'Attended' in your equal statement.

```
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = 'Attended' and BEI.ATTENDED = 'Attended'
```

This will return users who attended both events and who were invited

```
WHERE EI.ATTENDED = 'Attended' or BEI.ATTENDED = 'Attended'
```

You may want to see what your results yield with and 'Or' statement

Its hard to determine what you have or are trying to do with limited table/data structure

Comment: The total number of business and alumni attendees at each event.